# how to start camera on Loading application in ANdroid?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can I start the camera as soon as the android application starts? My code is as follows
but it starts the camera on button click.

```
runBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_run_demo);
runBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }
});
```

Comment: Move code from `onclick()` to `oncreate()`?

Answer (score 0):

Write this lines of code in oncreate()

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code

> Intent cameraIntent = new
>   Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
>   startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method so when your app starts, the intent will be loaded. Haven't tested it, but it should work.